# Android load view while waiting for Volley response

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-volley

I have a fragment that show an image slider with remote images (I have used the AndroidImageSlider library). In the OnCreateView I do a volley request where i get the urls of the images. the problem is that volley is **asynchronous** and the slider get a NUllPointerException because OnCreateView doesn't wait the response with urls.

How can I load the fragment and tell the slider to wait for the urls?

This is a code example with only one image (for semplicity).

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apartment, container, false);

        getApartmentData(); // volley request. It set the image_url field

        // image slider
        imgSlider = (SliderLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.img_slider);
        imgSlider.stopAutoCycle();
        HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        url_maps.put("name1", image_url);

        for(String name : url_maps.keySet()){
            DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getActivity());
            defaultSliderView
                    .image(url_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
            imgSlider.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
        }
        imgSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Default);
        imgSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        imgSlider.setDuration(4000);
        imgSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: place ur problematic code

Comment: @krishna-v code posted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved putting this code inside the OnResponse of the volley request:

```
    HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
    url_maps.put("name1", image_url);

    for(String name : url_maps.keySet()){
        DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getActivity());
        defaultSliderView
                .image(url_maps.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
        imgSlider.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
    }
```